# JSON.stringify and JSON.parse get different result

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have an Object I use JSON.stringify to create JSON string.
Than I save that string into file.
Then I read that file. Make JSON.parse and try to use that object again.
But it does not work anymore.
For example if I use  [i] to select element it doesnt select element but just take charset like its a string :(

Can any body help with that?

This is some kind of example but actuall JSON is toooo long:

```
{"featureCollection":
{"layers":"[
    {\"layerDefinition\": 
        {\"currentVersion\": 10.3,
                         \"id\": 0, 

                                     \"supportsCoordinatesQuantization\": true,
                                     \"advancedQueryCapabilities\": 
                                     {  
                                        \"supportsPagination\": true,

                                        \"supportsDistinct\": true
                                    }, 
                                    \"geometryType\": 
                                        \"esriGeometryPolygon\", \"minScale\": 0,
                                        \"maxScale\": 0,
                                        \"extent\": 
                                            {},
                                        \"drawingInfo\":
                                            {\"renderer\": 
                                                {\"type\": \"simple\", \"symbol\": 
                                                    {\"type\": \"esriSFS\", \"style\": \"esriSFSSolid\", \"color\": [76, 129, 205, 191], \"outline\": 
                                                        {\"type\": \"esriSLS\", \"style\": \"esriSLSSolid\", \"color\": [0, 0, 0, 255], \"width\": 0.75}
                                                    }
                                                },
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON string? or at least a portion of it?

Comment: I added in a question

Comment: Solution: Only stringify the *root* of your data structure.

Answer (score 4):

What's going on is that the `layers` property of the `featureCollection` property is not an array, it's a JSON encoding of an array. You need to decode it again to process the contents. Assuming `json_obj` is the full object, you need to do:

```
var layers = JSON.parse(json_obj.featureCollection.layers);
```

Then you can access `layers[i].layerDefinition.currentDefinition`.

I don't know why it's done that way -- you may want to fix the code that creates the JSON in the first place, and remove the part that calls `JSON.stringify()` when storing into the `layers` property.

Comment: Thank you! yes this thing work for me. Firstly I tried to replace escape charset but it didnt work. But anyway thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the process that is writing the JSON string to a file is escaping the quotes which is causing the issues when you try to parse. You either need to stop the process from escaping the quotes, or use `replace` to strip out the escaped quotes of your JSON string prior to passing it to `parse`

Comment: It's not happening when the JSON is being written to the file. Notice that the first two lines aren't escaped.

Comment: Good eye, didn't catch that.